# phpDocumentor generate class hierarchy diagram

Tags: class-diagram, phpdoc, class-hierarchy

I am discovering phpDocumentor to generate documentation from my php code. I achieved to generate a html file with the api documentation. But I found a tab called "class hierarchy diagram" which is empty. I looked on the documentation of phpDoc but there is no explication. Could you help me in generating this diagram ?
Thank you ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to generate it by using the undocumented setting --setting=graphs.enabled=true

see https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/issues/2365

It used the either graphviz or plantuml which have to be installed but there isn't much difference in the output and on Windows it is nearly impossible to use it since the setup is complicated as hell.
However the output is imho not really good since the classes doesn't show attributes or methods. Also the connector crossed which makes it hard to understand. As far as I see in the github post mentioned it is a feature which is still unfinished.

So I would recommend to create it manually so you can make it as detailed as you want it to be.